# Bootstrap 3 grid doesn't scale on mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a problem with Bootstrap 3 - when I check the responsive features on my desktop by scaling down the page it works fine. It also works well on responsinator.com, etc. (scr from desktop testing : 
But when I try to view it on my mobile phone with Android, it gets all the styling it should, given in my CSS, but bootstrap grid doesnt scale properly - it looks just like the desktop version but scaled down. I use media queries like this `@media screen and (max-width: 768px),screen and (max-device-width: 768px)`, could this be a problem? If needed, there is my CSS file : http://pastebin.com/zsUQ78q5. I have include the `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">` tag in my index file. Screenshots here : https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vTp9.jpg (1 - testing on desktop, 2 - actual look on mobile - like desktop version, grid not made "responsive")

EDIT : The problem occurs when i use *.tk alias, when I enter my website using original domain it works just fine. Anybody has some idea why it happens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably need to add the `viewport` tag to the `<head>` section of your HTML:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: Yeah I noticed too late, was wondering if it was in the `<body>` instead of the `<head>` though. I can't think of any other reason why this happens. Do you perhaps have the html + css live on a webserver? Or can you create a jsfiddle from it?

Comment: It's definitely in the `<head>`. If you're so kind to check it, it's online here : http://psychiatraplockgostynin.pl/123/

Comment: I guess it's indeed the `max-width: 768px` media query. The screenshot also indicates that the screen of your mobile if larger than 768px. Perhaps make it a larger number (or only a larger number of it has landscape orientation?)

Comment: It actually looks the same on vertical screen orientation. I can't seem to work it out :( My thoughts are now going towards some elements having display:flex maybe?

Comment: It looks fine both in landscape and portrait mode on my iPhone (as far as I understand the issue). I can only suggest you to make the problem easier to grasp by removing html and css until the issue disappears or is isolated.

Comment: 'Fine' like for example the menu is stacked like on the first picture? I'll check on another android device in a while

Comment: OMG, it really is ok when you view it using this URL! The problem occurs when i use *.tk alias, baxet-psych.tk . It surely isn't a problem no more, but maybe someone has any idea why this happen? .tk alias is set-up as URL forwarding. Anyway, thank you for your time, you did help me :)

Comment: .tk opens your page in a frame. The .tk page itself doesn't have the viewport tag :)